# need to get the nearest minimum and maximum values

Tags: php, mysql

Here I have a query regarding the getting nearest minimum and maximum values.
I have a range :

```
2.43 - 3.57 lakhs
```

Now i need to get the nearest values to minimum and maximum values.

I have tried with this query didn't get the desired result.

```
$othsimlar_prices = "select ABS(exshowroom - ".$price_query['minprice'].") as minprice,
                            ABS(exshowroom - ".$price_query['maxprice'].") as maxprice,
                            make,
                            model 
                    from ncp_variant_cache 
                    order by maxprice";
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you want the nearest minprice and the nearest maxprice from possibly different rows, or the row which has the nearest combination? If 2 different rows, from which row do you want the make and model?

Comment: Actually i need the nearest prices range...with the exshowroom field only

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use 'where' and 'and' ?

```
$othsimlar_prices = "select * 
                    from ncp_variant_cache
where minprice=ABS(exshowroom - ".$price_query['minprice'].")
and maxprice=ABS(exshowroom - ".$price_query['maxprice'].")
                    order by maxprice"
```

;

OR if you have only one column with price you could just:

select * from your_table where price between interval1 and interval2

Comment: This not an answer. Always use comment box for providing any suggestions.

Comment: I updated my answer, so if you are nice to upvote me back to 0. Thank you and sorry for my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Crude way to get it:-

```
SELECT exshowroom ,
        make,
        model,
        0 AS range_diff
FROM ncp_variant_cache 
WHERE exshowroom BETWEEN ".$price_query['minprice']." AND ".$price_query['maxprice']."
UNION
SELECT exshowroom ,
        make,
        model,
        ABS(exshowroom - ".$price_query['maxprice'].") AS range_diff
FROM ncp_variant_cache 
WHERE exshowroom > ".$price_query['maxprice']."
UNION
SELECT exshowroom ,
        make,
        model,
        ABS(".$price_query['minprice']." - exshowroom) AS range_diff
FROM ncp_variant_cache 
WHERE exshowroom < ".$price_query['minprice']."
ORDER BY range_diff
LIMIT 1
```

This uses 3 unioned queries. The first gets any record that is within the price range, the 2nd gets the record closest to the max pricewhile the 3rd gets the record closest to the min price. The result is ordered by the difference (with ones within the range having the difference set to 0) limited to 1 row back.